# Como usar um JComboBox de uma classe em outra?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Estou querendo criar duas telas, uma cadastra os valores do JCombobox e na  outra eu utilizo os valores. Eu consigo recuperar o Combobox mas não aparece nenhum valo.

Classe do cadastro

```
public class Combo extends JFrame{

    private JButton ok,proxima;
    private JTextField texto;
    private JComboBox<String> meucombo;


    public JComboBox getMeucombo() {
        return meucombo;
    }

    Combo() {

        super("ComboBox");
        mCombo();
    }

    private void mCombo() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        acaoBotao acao = new acaoBotao();
        outroBotao outroBotao = new outroBotao();

        meucombo = new JComboBox<String>();

        proxima = new JButton("proxima");
        proxima.addActionListener(outroBotao);

        ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(acao);

        texto = new JTextField();

        add(meucombo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(texto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(proxima,BorderLayout.EAST);


    }

    private class acaoBotao implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            meucombo.addItem(texto.getText());
            texto.setText("");

        }
    }

    private class outroBotao implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Teste teste = new Teste();
            teste.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Outra classe

```
public class Teste extends JFrame {

    Teste(){

        super("teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        Combo combo = new Combo();
        JComboBox mcombo = combo.getMeucombo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(mcombo);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar o combo como argumento no construtor da nova classe:

```
private class outroBotao implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Teste teste = new Teste(meucombo);
        teste.setVisible(true);
    }
```

E na classe Teste:

```
public class Teste extends JFrame {

    Teste(JComboBox combo){

        super("teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        Combo combo = new Combo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(combo);

    }

}
```

Mas acredito que essa abordagem não seja boa. O componente deve ser construindo na mesma tela que ele faz parte. O que seria mais adequado, acredito eu, é persistir de alguma forma os dados do combo e utilizar estes dados na nova tela, assim não precisa ficar criando o componente num lugar e adicionando em outro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, é só uma atividade de sala por isso não necessita de banco. Agradeço

Comment: @RodolfoAllesson ah sim, nesse caso esa solução atende de boa :) Se a resposta lhe serviu você pode marca-la como aceita, clicando no `v` ao lado dela.